# Can't filter the data as category wise in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, filtering

## php data filtering with URL

I am developing an online shop, where I want to display category wise data. But I can't! Is there anything wrong to my code or URL?

**I pass the URL like below**

```
http://localhost/e-bookshop/users/all_books?ctg=1
```

### My Model:

```
public function get_books()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('category');
        $this->db->join('books', 'books.categoryId = category.id');

        if(isset($_GET['ctg']))
        {
            $a = $_GET['ctg'];
            $query = $this->db->where('category.id', '$a');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
        }
        $this->db->order_by('books.id', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

This doesn't show me any error, It just shows blank or nothing. How I can fix this problem? **Thanks advance.**

Comment: Can give a data set and the excepted output.

Comment: I am new here I did not know anything about this, bro.@MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very much close to what you have desired. I think your URL is okay.

The problem is here. You can not pass an array like that. You pass the array in the string format. For the apostope coma, URL can't read your array. You have to change this line.

```
 $query = $this->db->where('category.id', '$a');
```

Instead of this line, write like the below line

```
$query = $this->db->where('category.id', $a);
```

**I think this above line could solve your problem.** Just copy this line and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed my problem. Oh no this ' ' comma just destroy my 6 hours!!